# can't create database by xampp mysql command window

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I try to create a new database(m) in xampp mysql command window then I'm getting an error message

> "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   'm'".

Then I created that database by using phpmyadmin but its not shown in mysql command window when I type `show databases` command there. Can anybody tell me how can I get rid of that error message and can successfully create new database by using mysql command window in xampp? (I'm using windows xp professional service pack-2)

-Thanks.

Comment: Edit: My xampp file- 'xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9-installer',the installation process was fine and I kept all default settings,didn't change anything.

Comment: EDIT 2: mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> use m;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'm'

Comment: EDIT 3: New database can be created and all operations can be done by using phpmyadmin but that database is not shown in mysql command window and can't create new database by using 'create database' command.But can use 'test' database which is default there and can create and use tables within that.Just can't create any new database there.

Comment: (and in 'xampp\mysql\data\m' folder there just 1 file 'a.frm' is created for table 'a'.)

Comment: EDIT 4: In mysql 'shell' its working and all databases are shown there but in 'xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe' those databases aren't shown there and also can't create new database.

Comment: EDIT 5: Got a difference between two command windows.When I type 'select current_user;' in phpmyadmin or in mysql 'shell' then the result is 'root@localhost'. but in 'xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe' the result is '@localhost'.So 'root' is missing there.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use command window?.

Comment: can you post the answer as an answer and accept it please, so if anyone else has the same problem they can see your thought process and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***RESOLVED:***** Thanks to all for your kind replies. I solved that problem. 
**I changed the 'user' table in 'mysql' database by using phpmyadmin and set the fields to 'Y' while those were 'N' where host was 'localhost'(so localhost wasn't able to create or drop any database).Now its possible to create new database by 'xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe'.** 
***AND *****to get .frm(table definition), .MYD(table data) and .MYI(table indices) files for a table in mysql data folder,I SET **type=MyISAM** and **collation=utf8_general_ci** so it would be easy to copy the database to another pc or server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging as a root?

Browse to the mysql.exe containing foler and try typing this in the cmd:

```
mysql.exe -u root --password
```

Comment: I just installed xampp. No username or password.I can create table by using 'test' database which is there by default but can't create a new database.

Comment: There is always a root user, so try loggin with it, what happen when you execute the above commands in the command prompt?

Comment: Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> mysql.exe -u root --password;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
.exe -u root --password' at line 1
mysql>

Comment: type exit, or restart the cmd and then browse to the mysql folder and execute the commands.

Comment: I did that too but same result;

Answer (score 0):

Try to initiate your mysql client with a specific username and password ( if you have set one )

```
mysql.exe -uroot [-p]
```

Edit:
Add this to your my.cnf [client] section to log-in without any parameter

```
[client]
user=root
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: I don't use any username or password. just installed xampp.

Comment: you always have the default username root without a password. Verify your username by typing `SELECT CURRENT_USER;` into your SQL window in phpMyAdmin

Comment: '@localhost' is current user.

Comment: How did you start your MySQL server? Use the xampp control panel.

Comment: Yes,I use xampp control panel to start and stop apache and mysql server. Tried 'xampp_start' and 'xampp_stop' too but nothing changed.

Comment: in your `xampp control panel` you have a button `Shell` on the right side. press it and type   `mysql -uroot`, then try to create a database again

Comment: in 'shell' that worked and there shown all databases but in 'mysql.exe' those databases aren't shown there and also can't create new database.

Comment: Sorry but if that worked I don't understand your problem. My initial answer already suggested to add a username. Calling mysql.exe without any params should read defaults from the my.cnf or my.ini client section (config button in the control panel) you can set a default user there

Comment: Sorry, I added 'user=root' in my.ini file but same thing happened.

Comment: I added 'user=root' in [client] section in my.ini file and When I type 'select current_user;' in phpmyadmin or in mysql 'shell' then the result is 'root@localhost'. but in 'xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe' the result is still '@localhost'.So 'root' is missing there. why that happened ? is there any other file to which have to add that line or have to add that line more than one in my.ini file ?

Comment: # The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
user=root
# password       = your_password
port            = 3306 
socket          = "E:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

Answer (score 0):

I know you've solved the problem .I had the same problem ,but the answer is simple .Answer :if you type "localhost" in your browser ,after selecting the language , you can select "phpmyadmin" .then as you said you can click on the "Databases" tab ,then from the list of databases select "mysql" and eventually you can see that the last table of this database is "user" table.if you then click on the "browse" button right in front of the name of the table which is "user". now you can see the "user" table in detail.you can see under the "host" column there are 3 "localhost" cells ,but only one of them has value of "root" in the "user"
column which is the next .so if you want to connect mysql via command prompt , if you have not set password yet ,(  `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root`  ) not
(  `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe`   ) or not  (  `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p`  ) .